# Multiple SQL update queries spanned in few functions (pyodbc)

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a sql db-connection that among all other things, has a function to update (lets say 4) tables that are dependent on each other. I originally had the queries all together in one function `updates_all_in_one` which is working fine.

I am now trying to break this into split functions (as I might need to call partial updates and avoid rewriting the same code) such as `update1` ... `update4`.

However, I noticed when I use the splits and call them back to back in function `updates_call_subfunc`, right after calling `update1` it seems that the updates by that function are not inplace (so running into dependency issues as update1 is not applied) and if the connector class from one function to second one, does not communicate.

I read a bit online and seems if connection is part of a class it is kept open/shared, but I am not seeing why the updates in sequence fail.

Thanks

```py
import pyodbc as mdb

class DbHandlerSQL(object):
    def __init__(self, dbHost, dbName, dbUser, dbPass):
        if os.name=='posix':
            connStr = ('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server='+ dbHost +'; Database='+dbName+';UID='+dbUser+';PWD='+dbPass)
        else:
            connStr = ('Driver={SQL Server};Server='+ dbHost +'; Database='+dbName+';UID='+dbUser+';PWD='+dbPass)
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
        self.conn.timeout = 200 
        self.dbCursor = self.conn.cursor()

    #==================================================================
    def updates_all_in_one(self,myname, mytype, mysource, local_id):
        try:
            q1 = " update table1 \
                   set name=? , type=?, source=?  \
                   where local_id=?"
            self.dbCursor.execute(q1, (myname, mytype, mysource, local_id) )

            q2 = " update table2 \
                   set name=? , type=?, source=?  \
                   where local_id=?"
            self.dbCursor.execute(q2, (myname, mytype, mysource, local_id) )

            q3 = " update table3 \
                   set name=? , type=?, source=?  \
                   where local_id=?"
            self.dbCursor.execute(q3, (myname, mytype, mysource, local_id) )

            q4 = " update table4 \
                   set name=? , type=?, source=?  \
                   where local_id=?"
            self.dbCursor.execute(q4, (myname, mytype, mysource, local_id) )

        except:
            raise Exception('problem during uploading')    
       self.dbCursor.commit()

    #==================================================================
    def updates_call_subfunc(self,myname, mytype, mysource, local_id):
        self.update1(myname, mytype, mysource, local_id)
        ' Test 1

        self.update2(myname, mytype, mysource, local_id)
        ' Test 2

        self.update3(myname, mytype, mysource, local_id)
        ' Test 3

        self.update4(myname, mytype, mysource, local_id)
        ' Test 4

        self.dbCursor.commit()

    #==================================================================
    def update1(self,myname, mytype, mysource, local_id):
        q1 = " update table1 \
               set name=? , type=?, source=?  \
               where local_id=?"
        self.dbCursor.execute(q1, (myname, mytype, mysource, local_id) )

    #==================================================================
    def update2(self,myname, mytype, mysource, local_id):
        q2 = " update table2 \
               set name=? , type=?, source=?  \
               where local_id=?"
        self.dbCursor.execute(q2, (myname, mytype, mysource, local_id) )

    #==================================================================
    def update3(self,myname, mytype, mysource, local_id):
        q3 = " update table3 \
               set name=? , type=?, source=?  \
               where local_id=?"
        self.dbCursor.execute(q3, (myname, mytype, mysource, local_id) )

    #==================================================================
    def update4(self,myname, mytype, mysource, local_id):
        q4 = " update table4 \
               set name=? , type=?, source=?  \
               where local_id=?"
        self.dbCursor.execute(q4, (myname, mytype, mysource, local_id) )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "I run into dependency issues as if the connector class from one function to second one, does not communicate.", are you getting an Exception ? what exception ? possibly a stacktrace and example code that runs to replicate this

Comment: Aside - this feels like a database design issue. Multiple tables with same column structure might not be effectively normalized. Consider combining all tables in one with indicator field to run **one** `update`.

Comment: @Parfait, This is just a simplified example to avoid typing in all the code. It is not really the same columns.

Comment: @steff_bdh, lets say after I call func `update1`, in the body of `updates_call_subfunc` right after the call, it appears the updates expected by `update1` are not in place. Basically in full form `update2` checks for existence of updates by first function and since it's not there, it complains. Maybe I should only point out the updates by `update1` dont seem to be applied/visible after the function call.